# Explanation of indented blocks of code on python

Tags: python

```
def prime_check(num):
    """
    Function to check if a number is prime
    """
    for n in range(2,num):
        if num%n == 0:
            print(num, "is not prime")
            break
        else:
            print(num, "is not prime")
```

pardon me as i just started using stack over flow and i don't know how to show the syntax highlighting here. but looking at the code above, when i call the function and i pass in the integer (number 2) into the function, there is no result, also when i pass in the number 21, it says 21 is prime, which is wrong. however, when using the code from udemy, which is a bit similar to mine(except for indentation), the function works fine. i need help understanding the indentation difference and why it works. The udemy code is shown below.

```
def is_prime(num):
    '''
    Naive method of checking for primes. 
    '''
    for n in range(2,num):
        if num % n == 0:
            print(num,'is not prime')
            break
    else: # If never mod zero, then prime
        print(num,'is prime!')
```

notice the difference in indentation between my own code and theirs. Please i need to understand the difference. Help!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: In your code, the `else` belongs to the `if`, in their code it belongs to the `for`, as indicated by the indentation. Any Python tutorial should explain the role of indentation for forming blocks.

Comment: *i don't know how to show the syntax highlighting here* - please go through the tour and help pages - the least you could do.

Comment: [for-else](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) in Python3.

Comment: Also, the way your code is indented, if `num `is `2` then it will never enter the for loop, which is why there is no result.

Comment: There is no case in which your code could say that a number is prime. Both of the `print` calls say "is not prime".

Comment: Thanks guys, the for-else documentation has helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

`else` occurs if the `for` loop did not break out. [*See Documenation*.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: Looking at the first block of code I posted, when I pass in 2, there’s no answer. When I pass in 21, it says 21 is prime, which is wrong. These anomalies don’t happen when I pass in the same arguments in the second block of code. I really don’t know why

Comment: @Uche - Choose a prime number (7) - in the first block: it will fail the `if` statement and execute the `else` statement on each cycle. In the second block: it will never satisfy the `if` statement and then after the `for loop` the `else` is called. NOTE: The `else` will never be called if the `break` occurs.

Answer (score -2):

In the above program `else` statement is executed when the condition for the `for` loop when the `range` limit is execeeded that is fails.. i.e) `for` loop checks whether the `num` is divisible by `n` if it is divisible it returns `"Not a Prime Number"` ...After the `for` loop condition ends `else` part will be executed.

Comment: `else` occurs if the `for` loop did not break out.